# What should be called for re-negotiation in SSL_Read/SSL_Write

Tags: c, tcp, https, openssl, epoll

I'm trying to add OpenSSL into epoll, and the socket is in non-blocking mode.
A question confusing me is that: `SSL_read` might yield `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` and `SSL_write` might yield `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` because of SSL renegotiation.

So, my questions are:

1. If SSL_read yield `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE`, and I modify socket event to `EPOLLOUT`. Then, when the socket become writable later, what should I call, `SSL_read` or `SSL_write`? (the API doc said the same operation has to be repeated)
2. Similar to question (1), and the case is `SSL_write` yield `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ`.
3. If `SSL_read` yields `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE`, can I call `SSL_send` to send data next? (TCP is full duplex, but it seems OpenSSL can't read and write Independently...)
4. Similar to question (3), and the case is `SSL_write` yield `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ`.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You should restart the API you were attempting.

Thus, if `SSL_read` issues `WANT_WRITE`, call `SSL_read` again when the socket becomes ready for write. Similarly for `SSL_write`.

The [OpenSSL documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_read.html) only states that you need to repeat the call with the same arguments that were given when the blocking notification is given.

> **WARNING**
>
> When an SSL_read() operation has to be repeated because of SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ or SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE, it must be repeated with the same arguments.

Even though you want full-duplex operation, if the current operation is blocked pending a status, then you should queue up any new operations until the the blocked operation completes. This way you will avoid potential problems entering the SSL stack with a different operation than the one that triggered the blocking notification.

Comment: thanks~ how about question 3 and 4: What will happen if a SSL_read yield SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE, but I call SSL_write next to send data...

Comment: It might work, or it might not. And, the behavior may change from release to release. Because, the documentation does not speak to that. The use of *WARNING* seems to indicate it is important to restart the same operation, and not initiate a new operation.

Comment: Thanks. in fact I have the same opinion with you, but I was not sure, so ask this question here. It seems the best way is looking insight into the source code...